# change the title and url of ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have simple page where first page is loading directly(user will click on page and it will open one page with some images) once the user scroll and goes down it will load another set of images and so on so every time he goes to bottom of page new content will be loaded and in that content i am sending the  also so it should show last title but its showing first title only. i went to view source and saw only first page source as in view source i think it will load only first page and ajax call will not take place.
but in browser its working just fine images from new pages are loading and even images are not coming in view source. so i want to change the url and title of new page new page means last page ajax has given as output however first page also remains at the top . new pages are coming in bottom.

how to change the url and title so that it reflect last page title/url. here is my basic page

```
      <div id="last_msg_loader"></div>
```

in this div I am loading this content

```
     echo '<title>'.$row['name'].'</title>';
     echo '<div id="'.$row['idp'].'"  align="left" class="message_box" >';
     echo $row['name'];
     echo $row['cont'];
     echo '</div>';
```

you can check live at http://way2enjoy.com/jquery/threadpreview/245888

Comment: title tag should be only put inside HEAD and should be unique

Comment: @a-wolff i want to change the url so i think when user is scrolling down i can dynamically load new content refreshing even url and title.what you say\